# Find all parentheses in a string by pairs - Python 3

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to get a list of tuples with the indices of all sets of parentheses in a string.  I can find the left and right parens independently easily with list comprehensions:

```
s = "12(34)567"

left_parens = [i for i,j in enumerate(s) if j == "("]
right_parens = left_parens = [i for i,j in enumerate(s) if j == ")"]
```

The most logical way to turn these separate lists into a list of tuples with (left paren, right paren) pairs is with the zip function.

```
parens = zip(right_parens,left_parens)
print(list(parens))
```

From this I would expect to yield:

```
[(2,5)]
```

But instead, I get:

```
[(5,5)]
```

Even if I switch the order like this:

```
parens = zip(left_parens,right_parens)
```

The result is still [(5,5)].

What am I missing?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc49DsIwDAXgPaewMtlSFyg/U0@CEOrgUFeQRo47wOUDSFWVjqx@et9zetkwxbaUDB343R7bAx1PZ@/cg4PdUq8cf9FFIEwK0owgETjOT9beGDOBBBih@7bRX11SiYZVl5zKfaik/11a3ZoityJvSZuo2ewvL0k2XE5Uygc)

Comment: `right_parens = left_parens = ...` Typo?

Comment: Do you also need to handle nested parens correctly? If so, list comprehensions no longer suffice.

Comment: Note that these comprehensions do *not* match up the parens for you.  For that, there is a straightforward increment/decrement counting algorithm that will do the job cleanly.  If you get stuck, please post that as a separate question (but search first; I'm pretty sure there are at least two solutions already on SO).

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
right_parens = left_parens = [ ... ]
```

You set the two lists to the same memory area; they are now the same list.  Keep them separate:

```
left_parens  = [i for i,j in enumerate(s) if j == "("]
right_parens = [i for i,j in enumerate(s) if j == ")"]
```

EXTENSION

Note that your algorithm won't work for nested parentheses:

```
s = "1(2(34)56)7"
```

Output:

```
[(1, 6), (3, 9)]
```

You can solve this with a counter: pre-increment for each Lparen, post-decrement for each Rparen.  Mark each paren location with its nesting level:

```
string 1(2(34)56)7(8)
marker -1-2--2--1-1-1
```

From here, move from the inside out: match the 2's, left to right (only one pair), then the 1's (two pairs).  Coding is left as an exercise for the student.  :-)
From here, you can

Comment: wow,  I think it's time to call it a day.  Good catch.  I didn't even know you could do that in one line, so at least I learned something.  <insert facepalm meme here>.